# How to get a boolean data from my API and use it

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't get data from my back.

file.html

```
<div *ngIf="shouldDisplay">
  <p> information to disiplay </p>
  <button mat-flat-button type="button" (click)="update()">
     update
  </button>
</div>
```

file.ts

```
shouldDisplay: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.check();
  //this.shouldDisplay return undefined
  this.shouldDisplay = this.checkData;
}

check() {
  this.fileService.check().subscribe( data => {
  //data return true
  this.checkData = data;
 });
}

update(){
 this.check();
 //this.checkData return undefined
 if(this.checkData){
  this.fileService.update();
 }else{
  this.notificationService.error('errorMessage');
 }
}
```

I would like this.checkData to return true.
I would like to use this.checkData in the update method.

Comment: can you share what fileservice.check() does? you can also `this.shouldDisplay = this.checkData;` inside the subscribe to make it update on every check function execution.

Comment: fileservice.check() returns true or false. Yes I could do like that and it will work, but I would like to use this.shouldDisplay in another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `this.check()` is an asynchronous action and you want to do something when it's finished, you need to return the underlying `Observable` and subscribe to it from the other methods:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.check().subscribe(() => this.shouldDisplay = this.checkData);
}

check(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.fileService.check().pipe(
    tap(data) => this.checkData = data)
  );
}

update(): void {
  this.check().subscribe(() => {
    if (this.checkData) {
      this.fileService.update();
    } else {
      this.notificationService.error("errorMessage");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok and if I want to use this.shouldDisplay or this.checkData with the values that the check() method gave me that is (true or false) in another method how can I do.

Comment: It depends on what kind of a method you mean and when it's called. Please modify the code sample in the question to include it and we'll find a way.

Comment: okay I modified.

Comment: In this case it's necessary to subscribe to the observables from the other methods. I've updated the answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: in the check() method, what is 'tap'? and I have an error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Because this.checkData is a boolean and data is an Observable<boolean>

Comment: `import { tap } from 'rxjs`. As for the typescript error — you said `this.fileService.check()` returns `true` or `false`, however its return type is `Observable<Object>` in the `FileService` class. That's what the error says.

Comment: import { tap } from 'rxjs does not exist in my project.

Comment: Which version of `rxjs` are you using? I assumed you were on the current version: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap. If you're on v6, I think the right syntax is `import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';`.